# WPF - Need to enable scrolling in a disabled DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

My DataGrid columns are being added in code behind.

When the user is done editing rows and clicks on a Next button, DataGrid is disabled and user is taken to the next step which is in the same view..

The problem arises if user has a lot of rows and needs to scroll over the now disabled DataGrid to overview the rows.

I've tried wrapping the DataGrid (which is bound to a property that sets IsEnabled = false when user clicks on Next) in a ScrollViewer which gives me the desired effect but the scroll is then located outside the DataGrid which I find annoying.

I'm at my wits end and could really use some help how I should go about doing this.

I've also tried overriding the metadata for ScrollViewer which works somewhat but is unsafe from what I've read.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using the [IsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx) property you can use the [DataGrid.IsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.isreadonly%28VS.95%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 3):

Mark the `DataGrid` as ReadOnly and apply the following style to get the appearance like disabled (if required).

```
<DataGrid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property ="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the IsReadOnly property on the DataGrid and bound it to IsEnabled.

This was an apparent problem at first because IsEnabled was true making the DataGrid read-only in the wrong state.

So I created a helper class to convert the bool to false to reflect the correct states (enabled/disabled).

The components in the DataGrid have their IsEnabled property databound also which gives me the proper disabled styles for them when DataGrid is read-only.

Thanks for the help guys!